# How to find out whether or not a list is hidden without writing code (SP2010)?

Tags: 2010, list, caml, hidden

Does anyone know if there is a way of telling (without writing any code) whether or not a list is "hidden"?

I have a CAML query which contains the following and I'd like to eliminate the possibility that the "Hidden=false" property is affecting my query results.

```
query.Lists = "<Lists Hidden="FALSE" />";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, if list is not shown in "All site content", it is hidden :) And btw `<Lists Hidden="FALSE" />` doesn't make much sense anyway, since default value for Hidden is "FALSE" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx), so by default it will fetch all non-hidden lists. Honestly, I'm afraid I don't understand the question... Can you elaborate/rephrase?

Comment: Thanks Andrey, this makes little difference though; my original question still stands.

Comment: Hi Andrey, I would like to know if there's a way of using the SharePoint interface to find out if a list is hidden, for example, perhaps a tick box hidden away in the library settings?

Comment: You can use PowerShell to show all the hidden lists of a site. If you know URL of a hidden list you can access it but it will not be shown in the "All site content" (_layouts/viewlsts.aspx). But there is no any "tick box" out there: you can make a list hidden only programmatically or via PowerShell or you can also define it in list CAML definition.

Comment: So if the list appears in "View All Site Content" it is not hidden - is this method a reliable indicator? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes it is absolutely reliable. You're welcome!